# How to search for words starting with given lettter

Tags: algorithm, search, prolog

I want to implement a search function in Prolog where when I type a letter it shows suggested words, starting from that letter dynamically.

As a starting point I tried to find a way to get a list of words starting from the given letter. But I couldn't find anything to try.

Comment: Someone please give me an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a worthy project, not only for a beginner. Most of complexity would be deserved to user interaction. You should subdivide your task - first though:

- words representation
- user interaction (what media?)

  - 'next char' acquisition
  - list display
  - error handling?

For instance, with basic Prolog IO and vanilla words' database:

```
word("prolog").
word("programming").
word("algorithm").
word("word").

user_interface(SelectedSoFar, SelectedWord) :-
  % get a sorted set of matched words rest
  (  setof(Rest, Word^(word(Word), append(SelectedSoFar, Rest, Word)), Matched)
  -> (  Matched = [Choosed]  % only 1 choice available ?
     -> append(SelectedSoFar, Choosed, SelectedWord) % terminate
     ;  % display list, get next char, recurse
        forall(member(Rest, Matched), format('~s^~s~n', [SelectedSoFar, Rest])),
        get(C),
        append(SelectedSoFar, [C], ExtendedSel),
        user_interface(ExtendedSel, SelectedWord)
     )
  ;  writeln('no match, retry'),
     append(WithoutLast, [_], SelectedSoFar), % discard last - BUG: swapped arguments
     user_interface(WithoutLast, SelectedWord)
  ).
```

sample interaction:

```
?- user_interface("",W).
^algorithm
^programming
^prolog
^word
|: w

W = "word".

?- user_interface("",W).
^algorithm
^programming
^prolog
^word
|: p
p^rogramming
p^rolog
|: r
pr^ogramming
pr^olog
|: o
pro^gramming
pro^log
|: g

W = "programming".
```

*EDIT*: I've corrected a bug, see comment % discard last....

where you see (for instance)

```
|: w
```

I input a char *and* a 'carriage return'. This is a really rudimental interface... You should at least accept a string, instead of a single char. See you Prolog manual about that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Sorry for late reply, I tried to understand your code, but failed. And it itself didn't work. Can you please further explain me what I can do.

Comment: didn't work? I tested it, what you see it's the actual running... Anyway the core matching it's done by `append(SelectedSoFar, Choosed, SelectedWord)`

Comment: `% c:/Users/compaq/Desktop/tst2.pro compiled 0.02 sec, 6 clauses
1 ?- user_interface("",W).
^algorithm
^programming
^prolog
^word
|: w

false.`

This is what I get, surely something must be wrong with me. This is with SWI-Prolog 6.2.6,
Any other things to be asserted other than word and user_interface? 
                                                                First I tried with amzi prolog and it didn't gave any answer other than "no".

Comment: Please tell me what is the prolog compiler you are using. 
I need to use prolog with a user friendly GUI supporting programming language, What is the best and easiest prolog combination for Java and C#.

Comment: I'm using SWI 6.3.15, but I'm fairly sure should work with your as well. Try `?- leash(-all),trace.` That will print the inner workings on console. I just tried Java via JPL, it's working but not too easy. Don't know about C#

Comment: Now just tested under Windows, with version 6.3.13, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a data structure called a *trie*. You can read about them at

- http://www.sarathlakshman.com/2011/03/03/implementing-autocomplete-with-trie-data-structure/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie
- http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/trie/

Any good algorithm book, such as Robert Sedgewick's [*Algorithms*](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/), will go into tries in some detail. Here's a paper that might be useful, [*Fast Algorithms for Sorting and Searching Strings*](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/strings/paper.pdf) , by Jon Bentley and Robert Sedgewick.

A little *google-fu* suggests that [YAP Prolog](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/) has a [built-in trie implementation](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/documentation.html#Tries), per its manual. Here's a discussion about a trie implementation in prolog: http://computer-programming-forum.com/55-prolog/59e7d719f1e1d18f.htm

I suspect you'll find that representing a trie in prolog is relatively simple. The work will be in populating the tree from a dictionary. Writing a progrom to read your dictionary and generate the trie as prolog facts will be the harder part.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It seems you have suggested a good way. I am still studying what you have told. Will come back to you soon with better understanding. Answer of my question seems very complicated than I thought.